# Circular buffer in virtual memory on esp32?

Tags: rust, embedded, esp32

[This article](https://abhinavag.medium.com/a-fast-circular-ring-buffer-4d102ef4d4a3) describes using mmap to configure two virtual memory ranges to the same underlying buffer to avoid memory copies for managing circular buffers.

Can esp32 hardware support this?  I’d like to use an i2c dma technique to read microphone audio data directly into a circular buffer and hand off windowed ranges of that buffer to tensorflow for analysis all on an esp32 without any avoidable memory copies.

[This reddit](https://amp.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/9eqfq4/libc_mmap/) thread discusses it, but I don’t know enough to interpret the answer.  Can those api calls map to memory?  Is there an alternative mechanism to achieve my efficiency goals?

Comment: Have you looked at a so called, "Bipartite Buffer"? It is implemented in a circular fashion but allocates contiguous areas suitable to DMA into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ESP32 doesn't have virtual memory - at least not with RAM.

The reddit thread talks about making parts of Flash available from a specific address in the internal 32-bit address space. I guess this could be considered a form of virtual memory but it's quite limited - you can only do it for Flash and only in 64 KiB chunks.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any other neat technique for ~processing the last few seconds of audio ~every half-second that beats having to memcopy to a contiguous buffer?

Comment: I guess compared to copying, having the DMA somehow write the duplicates wouldn't be the worst thing.  Double the sample rate and then deinterlace to two buffers?  Wire a single channel to two channels & buffers?

Comment: I suppose you could implement a pool of buffers where an incoming sample reserves a buffer, writes into it, sends it into your processing pipeline, then releases the buffer back into the pool once the sample has been processed?

Comment: To me, the key challenge is processing overlapping windows so that we don’t need to delay results by the minimum length of the signal being sought, or worry about a legit signal being lost straddling two sequential buffers.  An infinitely long buffer could work for this, but … wasteful.  A circular buffer works only until the current window wraps - a copy would be required to send a single contiguous buffer to a typical api that accepts only a single contiguous buffer.  A cost free duplicate of buffers adjacent in memory could always contain a contiguous region without cpu memcopying.

Comment: You're working with simple, direct memory access and addressing. Perhaps you could make a copy only when data wraps in the circular buffer and not otherwise. In any case I suspect any potential solution would arrive through you typing it in, as the system won't provide off-the-shelf solutions :)